# What is a real-world example of Dependency Injection in a Dynamic Language?

Tags: python, .net, ruby, dependency-injection, angularjs

I have a thorough background in .NET but have been using Python and Ruby lately. I found myself pondering how to best provide dependencies to objects that need them in Ruby.

At first thought, I did not actually think DI and IoC frameworks would be required to interact with dependencies because of the leniency of dynamic languages (a la redefinition, mixins, stubs, etc). Then, however, I came across answers as to why DI/IoC frameworks are **not needed** in dynamic languages. The reasons provided don't sit too well with me. I'm hoping I can see an example that might clear things up.

### Recommended suggestions that I kind of disagree with:

#### Reason 1: A dependent class can be changed at run time (think testing)

In [Why are IOC containers unnecessary with dynamic languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273683/why-are-ioc-containers-unnecessary-with-dynamic-languages/2308494#2308494) we see that a dependent class (non-injected), say `X`, can be stubbed or mocked in a test. Sure, but that requires us to know our `System Under Test` is depending on something called `X`. If our `System Under Test` suddenly depends on `N` instead of `X`, we must now remember to mock `N` instead of `X`. The benefit of using DI is we'd never accidentally run a test with production dependencies because we'd always be passing in mocked dependencies.

#### Reason 2: Subclass or use constructor injection for testing

In everyone's favorite goto resource for all things DI + Ruby, [LEGOs, Play-Doh, and Programming](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/11/9/legos-play-doh-and-programming), we see an example of subclassing a System Under Test to mock dependencies. Alternatively, we can use constructor injection. Okay, so `B` depends on `A`. We call `B.get_dependency` which provides `B` with an instance of `A`. But what if `A` depends on `N` which depends on `X`? Must we call `get_dependency` on each successive object in the chain?

#### Reason 3: Dependencies can be mixed in or monkeypatched

[Fabio mentions](http://fabiokung.com/2010/05/06/ruby-and-dependency-injection-in-a-dynamic-world/) we can just use mixins/monkeypatch. So `X` is mixedin to `N`. But The issue is what if `X` depends on `A` which depends on `B`? Do we just use mixins for every dependency down the chain? I see how that can work but it could get messy and confusing quickly.

---

Side note: [Many users say](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dependency%20injection%20dynamic%20language) DI frameworks are not needed in dynamic languages. However, Angular.JS has really benefited from implementing a pretty solid DI system. Angular is built on JavaScript, a dynamic language. Is this approach comparable to Ruby or Python?

Please keep in mind I'm not saying I want to *force* DI/IoC into Ruby, Python, etc.

Comment: I agree with your assessment. Dynamic languages are less coupled than statically compiled languages, that doesn't mean the same sane software engineering principles don't apply. Implicitly substituting a whole class definition for another is not the same as mocking and injecting a dependency.

Comment: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/11/9/legos-play-doh-and-programming - a great read on the subject.

Comment: http://fabiokung.com/2010/05/06/ruby-and-dependency-injection-in-a-dynamic-world/ is a good reply to Jamis Buck's article.

Comment: @JonasElfström I referred to that first post (Jamis Buck) in my original question. I actually don't think it's that great of a read. Refer to Reason 2 in my original question. Thanks.

Comment: For me, Dependency Injection is a technique enabling me to write composable code. The lightbulb moment for me was seeing my code split neatly into two distinct responsibilities: 'wiring' and 'building blocks'. I look for a way to achieve this in whatever language I am using.

Comment: Sorry for my, apparently, sloppy read of your question. Since you didn't like the article and I did I guess it was of even less help to you. What is that `get_dependency` you mentioned? I couldn't find it in Buck's article and I don't quite understand what you are getting at.

Comment: No worries. In Buck's article, uses `B.new_client`. I called it `get_dependency` in my SO questions because it was more generic and was afraid people who didn't read the article wouldn't know what I meant. If you have any suggestions, I'd love to see them.

Comment: I agree with Nigels description. The first question you must ask yourself is do you really need DI, there are many other ways to achieve good separability. For examples look at: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: The cat is once again out of the bag! http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2012/dependency-injection-is-not-a-virtue.html

Answer (score 2):

While many think DI is not needed, I agree with you, that it's indeed needed a lot; but sometimes it gets mixed with other techniques Python provides. I suggest you to look at [venusian](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/venusian), it may kind of verbose, but if you come from .NET you'll see the relation. In a word: venusian allows you to annotate your methods without changing their behavior. Thus, you may write venusian decorators so that your unit-testing does not get affected. [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/docs/pyramid.html) uses venusian to annotate views, for instance.