# Is there a recommended way to manage application configuration and wiring?

Tags: ruby, configuration, sinatra, ioc-container, sequel

I am not using Rails, but I'm using Sinatra, Sequel and some asynchronous messaging library. I am looking for some recommendation about how to do the wiring.

In a Java world, my natural choice would have been Spring. But I know Ruby is different, and I've been reading [this question about IoC in dynamic languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273683/why-are-ioc-containers-unnecessary-with-dynamic-languages) and [this nice post from Fabio Kung](http://fabiokung.com/2010/05/06/ruby-and-dependency-injection-in-a-dynamic-world/), which make sense.

What I am missing is the practical side of the solution. I am looking for an elegant solution to manage my application level wiring in a way that is readable, concise and allows me to test and eventually re-wire my application components in test-specific ways.

Is there any reference about how to manage application configuration? Or any specific project I should have a look to?

Comment: By the way I am also having a look to [Jamis Buck video from RubyConf 2008](http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/recovering-from-enterprise.html) and feeling somewhat stupid :-)

Comment: This is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Perhaps it would fair better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, which is more suited to white-board type discussions.

Comment: You might be right... :-) can I migrate it, or do I need some external intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few resources that I would consider for app configuration:

https://github.com/markbates/configatron

http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file

https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic

Comment: Thanks @Unixmonkey, they all look interesting! And yes, you're on spot. :-)